# Why are there two brackets [ in the c++ vertex functions?

Tags: c++, shader, metal, metalkit

I am watching the introduction video's from Apple about Metal and MetalKit.

The sample code for the shaders has these double brackets like `[[buffer(0)]]` arguments. Why are there two brackets? Does it mean anything or is it just to indicate that there is keyword "buffer" following? There is no such construct in standard c++, is there?

```
vertex Vertex vertex_func(constant Vertex *vertices [[buffer(0)]],
                              constant Uniforms &uniforms [[buffer(1)]],
                              uint vid [[vertex_id]])
```

Also what would be a good 1 or 2 week fun project as an introduction into GP-GPU? Something manageable for a novice with good math skills but no artistic skills.

Comment: Yes, this is a standard syntax. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes

Comment: Also, shameless plug for a playground that I wrote which might be helpful if you are just learning how to use Metal: https://github.com/jtbandes/Metalbrot.playground

Comment: Oh, so it's an _attribute_ that just says where to find the vertices variable. Wake up Brain. I was too hung up on the double [. Still, any idea why they choose two [ instead of just one?

Comment: Probably to avoid ambiguities with regular array subscripting syntax. `int x[length];` vs. `int x[[some_attr]];`.

Comment: Probably. Still in a function header I would expect more doStuff([int] x) or doStuff(x: [Int]) and not doStuff(int x[length]). What would that even mean? Then again, I am also new to c++. If you put your answer in a reply, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are called *attributes*, and their syntax and behavior are defined in section 7.6.1 of the C++ standard, *Attribute syntax and semantics*. They look like this in the grammar:

```
attribute-specifier:
    [ [ attribute-list ] ]
    alignment-specifier
```

The Metal shading language defines numerous attributes that allow you to associate various semantics with variables, `struct`/`class` members, and function arguments (including argument table bindings as in your question).

The [Metal Shading Language Specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/metal-shading-language-specification.pdf) defers to the C++ standard on this, so the C++ standard really is the reference to consult:

> The Metal programming language is based on the C++14 Specification
>   (a.k.a., the ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/ WG21 N4431 Language Specification)
>   with specific extensions and restrictions. Please refer to the C++14
>   Specification for a detailed description of the language grammar.

Comment: Was also going to add that the `[[buffer(0)]]` argument mentioned is created by the render command encoder. It sets up an argument table of resources to send to the shaders:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Render-Ctx/Render-Ctx.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH7-SW10

So it can set up buffers, textures, and samplerStates to be referred to by subscript as this is doing with the `buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]`.

Comment: The parameter attribute identifies the resource "slot" of the corresponding buffer object as set on the render command encoder at the time of the current draw call or compute command.

Answer (score 3):

With this [[ x ]] you declare att that are getting passed between shaders ans CPU

I quote:

> The [[ … ]] syntax is used to declare attributes such as resource
>   locations, shader inputs, and built-in variables that are passed back
>   and forth between shaders and CPU

Comment: Where comes the quote from? Please specify.